# how can I seek ndk-build runtime configuration at complie process time

Tags: android-ndk

How can I see ndk-build configuration at build console prompt?

I would like to see real/full compile line like below when ndk-build

```
gcc -o XXX -IYYY/ZZZ  -IAAA/BBB -std=c++0x
```

to confirm confused include-path, build option etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `ndk-build -n` to display the "real" commands. From `ndk-build --help`:

```
-n      Don't actually run any commands; just print them.
```